# How to apply css class for selected element in jquery or javascript?

Tags: jquery, css

I am new to Jquery any one tell me how to select child elements
 please check my code

```
<ul class="orglisting">
   <li><a href="javascript:getOrgUsers();" class="orglistactive">orgName</a></li>
   <li>
      <a href="javascript:getOrgUsers();">orgName1</a>
      <ul id="dId">
         <li id="dId1"><a href="javascript:getDeptUsers('Sales','1','1');">Sales</a></li>
         <li id="dId2"><a href="javascript:getDeptUsers('Engineering','1','1');">Engineering</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="javascript:getOrgUsers();">orgName2</a>
      <ul id="dId">
         <li id="itbhanu"><a href="javascript:getDeptUsers('ITbhanu','1','1');">ITbhanu</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="javascript:getOrgUsers();">orgName3</a>
      <ul id="dId">
         <li id="Engineering"><a href="javascript:getDeptUsers('PvtLtd','Engineering','1','1');">Engineering</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

My problem is when i am select deparmentName i want to select change background color for parent tag(orgName) and selected deartmentName.

For Example i am selected in orgName1(orgName) in that i selected Enginnering (department) i want to change backgroundcolor for orgName1 and Engineering and again i selected orgName2 (orgName) and departmentName is ItBhanu i want to apply background color for those two and remove before apply background color.

How can i do this..

Comment: Please post your JS Code to understand your problem. Where is your code wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to remove some style from previous elements and apply news elements to New Ones.

First of all, create a class which shows elements has selected, something like:

```
.selected { background: #ddd; }
```

Then on jQuery you have to attach to the click event of your anchor `a` tags.

```
$("a").on('click', function() {
   //Now this is run when all `a` will be clicked

   //First lets remove selected class from previously selected items

   $('.selected').removeClass('selected');

   // And lets add selected to currect element and this parent

   $(this).addClasss('selected');
   $(this).parent('li').find('a:first').addClass('selected');


});
```

Comment: Hi i am using your code but i got object don't have addclass method exception in my browser

Answer (score 0):

Made a demo for you

```
    $( ".submitBtn" ).click(function() {
         $( "p:last" ).addClass( "selected highlight" );                       
    });
```

You can make changes according to your requirements and add your own css may be `onload` or on any `click` event

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/YNLwG/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#idOfElement').addClass('className');
```